# How to convert all nodejs files into one executable file

Tags: node.js

Currently, I'm using pkg module to convert it to a single exe file and it does only one main.js file, but on the root folder, it has multiple *.js files that are needed to run along with this. I want all packages and files to be executed with a single click without exposing the files or installing them on the machine.